# SVG CSS Transform Scale Animation Not Working on Safari or Firefox

Tags: css, svg

I created a SVG animation that works perfectly in Chrome but on Firefox and Safari, the scale animation goes all over the place. I've tweaked to where it'll work in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. It seems like it has something to do with transform-origin not working for all browsers even though I am using coordinates pixel values. I've tried transform-box:fill-box which is what seems to help in Firefox but not in Safari.

I also tried adding translate to the keyframes to the same coordinates used in transform-origin. That tends to work in Firefox but not in the other browsers

Is there a solution here that would work for all three browsers?

```css
body {
  background-color: #3D085F;
}
#Icon_Dot {
  animation-name: iconDot;
  animation-duration: .25s;
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 542.45px 110.3px;
}
#Circle_2, #Circke_3, #Circle_1 {
  transform-origin: 930px 379px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#Circke_3 {
  animation-name:rings;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 520px 89px;
}
#Circle_2 {
  animation-name:rings;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 520px 89px;
}
#Circle_1 {
  animation-name: rings;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 520px 89px;
}
@keyframes iconDot {
  from {
      transform: scale(0.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to {
      transform: scale(1.0);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes rings {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(1 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1 1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1 1);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1125.53 553.74">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1,.cls-16,.cls-7{fill:none}.cls-3{fill:#fff}.cls-16,.cls-7{stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10}.cls-7{stroke-width:31px}.cls-16{stroke-width:21px}
</style>
<clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M420.39 706.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V557.11a6.49 6.49 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.49v142.82a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-2" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M593.49 706.42a9.6 9.6 0 0 1-7.12-3.15L485.59 592.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 0-11.29 4.36v103.15a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5 6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V550.62a9.13 9.13 0 0 1 6.77 3l101.14 110.66a6.49 6.49 0 0 0 11.28-4.38V557.11a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-3" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M774 657.54V700a6.47 6.47 0 0 1-6.47 6.46A6.46 6.46 0 0 1 761 700V557.09a6.47 6.47 0 0 1 6.46-6.47h61.64c29 0 49.38 20.86 49.38 50.45 0 22.94-11.64 40.74-33.44 47.5a6.48 6.48 0 0 0-3.44 10l27.15 37.63a6.47 6.47 0 0 1-5.24 10.25 6.46 6.46 0 0 1-5.27-2.72l-35.51-49.9a6.44 6.44 0 0 0-5.26-2.72h-37a6.46 6.46 0 0 0-6.47 6.43zm0-24.84a6.46 6.46 0 0 0 6.46 6.46h46.74c18.1 0 38.32-11.07 38.32-38.09 0-13.63-7-39-38.32-39h-46.74a6.46 6.46 0 0 0-6.46 6.46z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-4" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M918.84 706.42a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V557.11a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5 6.49v142.82a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-5" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1098 706.42h-1.39a6.48 6.48 0 0 1-4.8-2.13L990.06 592.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 0-11.3 4.36v103.15a6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49 6.49 6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V550.62H967a6.51 6.51 0 0 1 4.79 2.11l101.93 111.55a6.5 6.5 0 0 0 11.28-4.38V557.11a6.49 6.49 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-6" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1137.22 686.32a6.05 6.05 0 0 1 8.3-1.93 90.28 90.28 0 0 0 47.58 13.94c27.89 0 43.21-12.77 43.21-32.35 0-22.56-22.78-27.67-47.46-32.56-17.46-3.41-56.83-7.67-56.83-41.08s30.65-44.48 54.91-44.48a87.49 87.49 0 0 1 44.39 11.62 6.08 6.08 0 0 1 2.13 8.52 6.06 6.06 0 0 1-8 2.11c-13.2-7.22-25.57-10.76-40-10.76-15.11 0-40.65 9.36-40.65 32.35 0 24 34.48 27.24 55.76 31.29 18.09 3.4 48.53 10.43 48.53 43.2 0 29.16-22.56 43.63-55.34 43.63-23.87 0-40.83-6.07-54.77-14.91a6.09 6.09 0 0 1-1.87-8.4z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-7" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1286.23 706.42a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5-6.49V557.12a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5-6.5 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.5v142.81a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-8" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1458.3 582.46a6.39 6.39 0 0 1-7.79-1.53 64.67 64.67 0 0 0-47.75-21.8c-36.18 0-65.77 32.14-65.77 69.6s29.59 69.17 65.77 69.17c21.94 0 36.31-7.57 47.91-21.06a6.37 6.37 0 0 1 7.42-1.63h.11a6.43 6.43 0 0 1 2.27 10c-12.39 14.8-30 24.54-57.71 24.54-43.63 0-78.75-36.39-78.75-81.09s35.12-81.09 78.75-81.09c25.56 0 44.15 9.46 57.38 24.86a6.44 6.44 0 0 1-1.84 10z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-9" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M727.37 562.12h-37.88a5.74 5.74 0 0 0-5.75 5.74v132.81a5.74 5.74 0 0 1-5.75 5.75h-1.48a5.74 5.74 0 0 1-5.75-5.75V567.86a5.74 5.74 0 0 0-5.75-5.74h-37.24a5.75 5.75 0 0 1-5.75-5.75 5.74 5.74 0 0 1 5.75-5.75h99.6a5.74 5.74 0 0 1 5.75 5.75 5.75 5.75 0 0 1-5.75 5.75z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-10" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1482.62 549.92h-6.23v18.37h-2.61v-18.37h-6.27v-2.2h15.11z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-11" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1485.24 568.29v-20.57h.45l9.72 12 9.74-12h.45v20.57h-2.6v-13.82l-7.61 9.52-7.56-9.52v13.82z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-12" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M794.26 752.84c0-2.1 1.69-3.62 4.13-3.62h1.34c2.94 0 3.7 1.35 5 4.29L819 785.22l14.38-31.71c1.27-2.94 2-4.29 5-4.29h1.17c2.44 0 4.12 1.52 4.12 3.62v48.87c0 1.76-.75 2.6-2.43 2.6h-.68c-1.6 0-2.35-.84-2.35-2.6v-45.93l-14.3 31c-1 2.27-2.19 3.61-5 3.61s-4-1.34-5-3.61l-14.22-31v45.93c0 1.76-.67 2.6-2.35 2.6h-.84c-1.6 0-2.28-.84-2.28-2.6z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-13" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M881.83 752.76a3.19 3.19 0 0 1 3.19-3.2h32.55c1.68 0 2.61.84 2.61 2.35v.51c0 1.6-.93 2.36-2.61 2.36h-30v18.75h24.03c1.68 0 2.61.84 2.61 2.36v.33c0 1.6-.93 2.36-2.61 2.36h-24.06v20.18h30.54c1.68 0 2.6.76 2.6 2.27v.51c0 1.6-.92 2.44-2.6 2.44H885a3.19 3.19 0 0 1-3.19-3.2z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-14" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M955.51 752.76a3.19 3.19 0 0 1 3.19-3.2h12.87c18.76 0 29.77 10 29.77 27.08S990.08 804 971.15 804H958.7a3.19 3.19 0 0 1-3.19-3.2zm16 46.17c15.31 0 24-8.07 24-22.12 0-13.88-8.92-22.21-23.89-22.21h-10.39v44.33z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-15" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1038.11 751.83c0-1.68.84-2.61 2.43-2.61h.76a2.29 2.29 0 0 1 2.52 2.61v49.88c0 1.76-.84 2.6-2.52 2.6h-.76c-1.59 0-2.43-.84-2.43-2.6z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-16" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1097.65 751.16c.59-1.43 1.6-2.11 4.29-2.11s3.7.68 4.29 2.11l19.94 51.47c.16.42-1.52 1.68-3.28 1.68a3.49 3.49 0 0 1-3.45-2.6l-6-15.48h-23.39l-5.88 15.48c-.76 2-2 2.6-3.28 2.6-1.69 0-3.37-1.26-3.2-1.68zm14 30l-9.85-25.57-9.83 25.57z"/>
</clipPath>  </defs>
<g id="Icon">
    <path id="Circke_3" data-name="Circke 3" class="cls-3" d="M958.7 333.84c32.57 1.46 56.66 32.38 44.85 64.42-12.24 33.23-53.33 40.51-78.75 17.41-4-3.68-10.08 2.32-6 6 29.51 26.82 78.07 19 92.72-20.06 14.06-37.49-14.41-74.58-52.81-76.3-5.48-.25-5.47 8.27 0 8.51z" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)"/>
    <path id="Circle_2" data-name="Circle 2" d="M1024.26 441l-3.79-3.42a88.31 88.31 0 0 0 6.2-7.69l4.19 2.92a91.24 91.24 0 0 1-6.6 8.19zm15.38-24.89l-4.78-1.8c-.62 1.51-1.15 3.06-1.85 4.54l-2.24 4.38 4.47 2.46 2.41-4.69c.75-1.6 1.35-3.27 1.99-4.9zm4-18.44l-5.1-.29-.11 2.41-.39 2.4a43.22 43.22 0 0 1-.89 4.78l5 1.19a50.84 50.84 0 0 0 1-5.21l.42-2.63zm-58.18 67.27l-1.18-5c-1.56.45-3.19.57-4.78.87l-2.39.39-2.42.09.27 5.1 2.66-.11 2.62-.41c1.76-.31 3.53-.46 5.23-.94zm17.59-6.93l-2.48-4.47-4.36 2.26c-1.49.69-3 1.23-4.54 1.86l1.8 4.78c1.63-.67 3.3-1.27 4.89-2zm15.22-11l-3.43-3.78a84.68 84.68 0 0 1-7.67 6.22l2.93 4.18a88.13 88.13 0 0 0 8.18-6.63zM959 461.36c-68.6-1.91-106.38-85.72-56.26-135.84s133.93-12.33 135.85 56.26c.15 5.46 8.66 5.48 8.51 0-2.12-75.94-94.9-117.76-150.38-62.28S883 467.76 959 469.88c5.48.15 5.47-8.36 0-8.52z" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#fff"/>
<path id="Circle_1" data-name="Circle 1" class="cls-3" d="M959 266.27c-5.48-.1-5.48-8.61 0-8.51 83.78 1.62 145.63 85 116.88 165.54-30.18 84.56-137.77 107.61-202.78 47.92-4-3.71 2-9.72 6-6 61.64 56.6 164.26 32.7 190-48.41 23.61-74.45-33.47-149-110.1-150.52zM837.29 406l10.1-1.55a146.73 146.73 0 0 1-1.45-15.61l-10.2.4a157.69 157.69 0 0 0 1.55 16.76zm8.71 29.11l9.23-4.38a83.2 83.2 0 0 1-5.3-14.31l-9.85 2.72a94.6 94.6 0 0 0 5.92 15.97zm17.15 25.05l7.48-7a97.85 97.85 0 0 1-9.52-12l-8.51 5.65a107.08 107.08 0 0 0 10.58 13.35zm-10.27-142l8.84 5.13c2.42-4.61 5.62-8.71 8.58-13l-8.09-6.24c-3.21 4.65-6.65 9.13-9.3 14.12zM840.8 345.9l9.79 2.91c.75-2.48 1.71-4.9 2.55-7.35l1.3-3.67 1.64-3.52-9.32-4.18-1.76 3.85-1.42 4c-.9 2.64-1.94 5.27-2.75 7.97zm-5 29.75l10.2.5a71.57 71.57 0 0 1 .57-7.75l1.15-7.68-10-1.86-1.26 8.36a81.78 81.78 0 0 0-.58 8.44zm86.51-113.2l2.68 9.85a48.82 48.82 0 0 1 7.43-1.64l3.74-.68c1.24-.22 2.51-.19 3.77-.29l-.81-10.18c-1.42.12-2.86.1-4.27.34l-4.21.75a57.31 57.31 0 0 0-8.25 1.86zm-27.84 12.23l5.4 8.67c2.14-1.44 4.49-2.49 6.72-3.77 1.14-.59 2.24-1.27 3.41-1.8l3.54-1.47-4-9.4-3.93 1.64c-1.29.58-2.5 1.32-3.76 2-2.36 1.38-4.95 2.57-7.3 4.14zm-23.4 19.09l7.38 7.07 5.54-5.45c1.89-1.77 4-3.3 5.95-5l-6.34-8c-2.16 1.82-4.44 3.5-6.49 5.44z" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)"/>
  </g>
<circle cx="542.45" cy="110.3" r="19.07" fill="#daa900" id="Icon_Dot" data-name="Icon Dot"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, as I said, its not for me. It works in Firefox and Chrome, not Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the elements you are transforming, have a `transform` on them already.  The animated `scale()` you are applying is overwriting the `translate()` that is already on them.

The fact that the browsers are handling this combination of transform change and transform-origin differently is a bug, and also a red herring.

What I have done below is move the existing `transform` to the parent group, and removed the `transform-origin` properties from the child elements.

```
<g id="Icon" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path id="Circke_3" />
  <path id="Circle_2" />
  <path id="Circle_1" />
</g>
```

The below example, now works correctly on both Chrome and Firefox.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Mac right now, so I can't test Safari.  But I hope that fixing the underlying problem will make this work there also.

```css
body {
  background-color: #3D085F;
}
#Icon_Dot {
  animation-name: iconDot;
  animation-duration: .25s;
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 542.45px 110.3px;
}
#Circle_2, #Circke_3, #Circle_1 {
  transform-origin: 930px 379px;
  opacity: 0;
}
#Circke_3 {
  animation-name:rings;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#Circle_2 {
  animation-name:rings;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: .6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#Circle_1 {
  animation-name: rings;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes iconDot {
  from {
      transform: scale(0.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to {
      transform: scale(1.0);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes rings {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(1 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1 1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1 1);
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1125.53 553.74">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1,.cls-16,.cls-7{fill:none}.cls-3{fill:#fff}.cls-16,.cls-7{stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10}.cls-7{stroke-width:31px}.cls-16{stroke-width:21px}
</style>
<clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M420.39 706.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V557.11a6.49 6.49 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.49v142.82a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-2" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M593.49 706.42a9.6 9.6 0 0 1-7.12-3.15L485.59 592.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 0-11.29 4.36v103.15a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5 6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V550.62a9.13 9.13 0 0 1 6.77 3l101.14 110.66a6.49 6.49 0 0 0 11.28-4.38V557.11a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-3" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M774 657.54V700a6.47 6.47 0 0 1-6.47 6.46A6.46 6.46 0 0 1 761 700V557.09a6.47 6.47 0 0 1 6.46-6.47h61.64c29 0 49.38 20.86 49.38 50.45 0 22.94-11.64 40.74-33.44 47.5a6.48 6.48 0 0 0-3.44 10l27.15 37.63a6.47 6.47 0 0 1-5.24 10.25 6.46 6.46 0 0 1-5.27-2.72l-35.51-49.9a6.44 6.44 0 0 0-5.26-2.72h-37a6.46 6.46 0 0 0-6.47 6.43zm0-24.84a6.46 6.46 0 0 0 6.46 6.46h46.74c18.1 0 38.32-11.07 38.32-38.09 0-13.63-7-39-38.32-39h-46.74a6.46 6.46 0 0 0-6.46 6.46z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-4" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M918.84 706.42a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V557.11a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5 6.49v142.82a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-5" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1098 706.42h-1.39a6.48 6.48 0 0 1-4.8-2.13L990.06 592.42a6.49 6.49 0 0 0-11.3 4.36v103.15a6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49 6.49 6.49 6.49 0 0 1-6.49-6.49V550.62H967a6.51 6.51 0 0 1 4.79 2.11l101.93 111.55a6.5 6.5 0 0 0 11.28-4.38V557.11a6.49 6.49 0 0 1 6.49-6.49 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-6" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1137.22 686.32a6.05 6.05 0 0 1 8.3-1.93 90.28 90.28 0 0 0 47.58 13.94c27.89 0 43.21-12.77 43.21-32.35 0-22.56-22.78-27.67-47.46-32.56-17.46-3.41-56.83-7.67-56.83-41.08s30.65-44.48 54.91-44.48a87.49 87.49 0 0 1 44.39 11.62 6.08 6.08 0 0 1 2.13 8.52 6.06 6.06 0 0 1-8 2.11c-13.2-7.22-25.57-10.76-40-10.76-15.11 0-40.65 9.36-40.65 32.35 0 24 34.48 27.24 55.76 31.29 18.09 3.4 48.53 10.43 48.53 43.2 0 29.16-22.56 43.63-55.34 43.63-23.87 0-40.83-6.07-54.77-14.91a6.09 6.09 0 0 1-1.87-8.4z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-7" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1286.23 706.42a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.5-6.49V557.12a6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.5-6.5 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 6.49 6.5v142.81a6.5 6.5 0 0 1-6.49 6.49z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-8" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1458.3 582.46a6.39 6.39 0 0 1-7.79-1.53 64.67 64.67 0 0 0-47.75-21.8c-36.18 0-65.77 32.14-65.77 69.6s29.59 69.17 65.77 69.17c21.94 0 36.31-7.57 47.91-21.06a6.37 6.37 0 0 1 7.42-1.63h.11a6.43 6.43 0 0 1 2.27 10c-12.39 14.8-30 24.54-57.71 24.54-43.63 0-78.75-36.39-78.75-81.09s35.12-81.09 78.75-81.09c25.56 0 44.15 9.46 57.38 24.86a6.44 6.44 0 0 1-1.84 10z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-9" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M727.37 562.12h-37.88a5.74 5.74 0 0 0-5.75 5.74v132.81a5.74 5.74 0 0 1-5.75 5.75h-1.48a5.74 5.74 0 0 1-5.75-5.75V567.86a5.74 5.74 0 0 0-5.75-5.74h-37.24a5.75 5.75 0 0 1-5.75-5.75 5.74 5.74 0 0 1 5.75-5.75h99.6a5.74 5.74 0 0 1 5.75 5.75 5.75 5.75 0 0 1-5.75 5.75z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-10" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1482.62 549.92h-6.23v18.37h-2.61v-18.37h-6.27v-2.2h15.11z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-11" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1485.24 568.29v-20.57h.45l9.72 12 9.74-12h.45v20.57h-2.6v-13.82l-7.61 9.52-7.56-9.52v13.82z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-12" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M794.26 752.84c0-2.1 1.69-3.62 4.13-3.62h1.34c2.94 0 3.7 1.35 5 4.29L819 785.22l14.38-31.71c1.27-2.94 2-4.29 5-4.29h1.17c2.44 0 4.12 1.52 4.12 3.62v48.87c0 1.76-.75 2.6-2.43 2.6h-.68c-1.6 0-2.35-.84-2.35-2.6v-45.93l-14.3 31c-1 2.27-2.19 3.61-5 3.61s-4-1.34-5-3.61l-14.22-31v45.93c0 1.76-.67 2.6-2.35 2.6h-.84c-1.6 0-2.28-.84-2.28-2.6z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-13" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M881.83 752.76a3.19 3.19 0 0 1 3.19-3.2h32.55c1.68 0 2.61.84 2.61 2.35v.51c0 1.6-.93 2.36-2.61 2.36h-30v18.75h24.03c1.68 0 2.61.84 2.61 2.36v.33c0 1.6-.93 2.36-2.61 2.36h-24.06v20.18h30.54c1.68 0 2.6.76 2.6 2.27v.51c0 1.6-.92 2.44-2.6 2.44H885a3.19 3.19 0 0 1-3.19-3.2z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-14" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M955.51 752.76a3.19 3.19 0 0 1 3.19-3.2h12.87c18.76 0 29.77 10 29.77 27.08S990.08 804 971.15 804H958.7a3.19 3.19 0 0 1-3.19-3.2zm16 46.17c15.31 0 24-8.07 24-22.12 0-13.88-8.92-22.21-23.89-22.21h-10.39v44.33z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-15" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1038.11 751.83c0-1.68.84-2.61 2.43-2.61h.76a2.29 2.29 0 0 1 2.52 2.61v49.88c0 1.76-.84 2.6-2.52 2.6h-.76c-1.59 0-2.43-.84-2.43-2.6z"/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-path-16" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M1097.65 751.16c.59-1.43 1.6-2.11 4.29-2.11s3.7.68 4.29 2.11l19.94 51.47c.16.42-1.52 1.68-3.28 1.68a3.49 3.49 0 0 1-3.45-2.6l-6-15.48h-23.39l-5.88 15.48c-.76 2-2 2.6-3.28 2.6-1.69 0-3.37-1.26-3.2-1.68zm14 30l-9.85-25.57-9.83 25.57z"/>
</clipPath>  </defs>
<g id="Icon" transform="translate(-387.89 -257.76)">
    <path id="Circke_3" data-name="Circke 3" class="cls-3" d="M958.7 333.84c32.57 1.46 56.66 32.38 44.85 64.42-12.24 33.23-53.33 40.51-78.75 17.41-4-3.68-10.08 2.32-6 6 29.51 26.82 78.07 19 92.72-20.06 14.06-37.49-14.41-74.58-52.81-76.3-5.48-.25-5.47 8.27 0 8.51z"/>
    <path id="Circle_2" data-name="Circle 2" d="M1024.26 441l-3.79-3.42a88.31 88.31 0 0 0 6.2-7.69l4.19 2.92a91.24 91.24 0 0 1-6.6 8.19zm15.38-24.89l-4.78-1.8c-.62 1.51-1.15 3.06-1.85 4.54l-2.24 4.38 4.47 2.46 2.41-4.69c.75-1.6 1.35-3.27 1.99-4.9zm4-18.44l-5.1-.29-.11 2.41-.39 2.4a43.22 43.22 0 0 1-.89 4.78l5 1.19a50.84 50.84 0 0 0 1-5.21l.42-2.63zm-58.18 67.27l-1.18-5c-1.56.45-3.19.57-4.78.87l-2.39.39-2.42.09.27 5.1 2.66-.11 2.62-.41c1.76-.31 3.53-.46 5.23-.94zm17.59-6.93l-2.48-4.47-4.36 2.26c-1.49.69-3 1.23-4.54 1.86l1.8 4.78c1.63-.67 3.3-1.27 4.89-2zm15.22-11l-3.43-3.78a84.68 84.68 0 0 1-7.67 6.22l2.93 4.18a88.13 88.13 0 0 0 8.18-6.63zM959 461.36c-68.6-1.91-106.38-85.72-56.26-135.84s133.93-12.33 135.85 56.26c.15 5.46 8.66 5.48 8.51 0-2.12-75.94-94.9-117.76-150.38-62.28S883 467.76 959 469.88c5.48.15 5.47-8.36 0-8.52z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#fff"/>
<path id="Circle_1" data-name="Circle 1" class="cls-3" d="M959 266.27c-5.48-.1-5.48-8.61 0-8.51 83.78 1.62 145.63 85 116.88 165.54-30.18 84.56-137.77 107.61-202.78 47.92-4-3.71 2-9.72 6-6 61.64 56.6 164.26 32.7 190-48.41 23.61-74.45-33.47-149-110.1-150.52zM837.29 406l10.1-1.55a146.73 146.73 0 0 1-1.45-15.61l-10.2.4a157.69 157.69 0 0 0 1.55 16.76zm8.71 29.11l9.23-4.38a83.2 83.2 0 0 1-5.3-14.31l-9.85 2.72a94.6 94.6 0 0 0 5.92 15.97zm17.15 25.05l7.48-7a97.85 97.85 0 0 1-9.52-12l-8.51 5.65a107.08 107.08 0 0 0 10.58 13.35zm-10.27-142l8.84 5.13c2.42-4.61 5.62-8.71 8.58-13l-8.09-6.24c-3.21 4.65-6.65 9.13-9.3 14.12zM840.8 345.9l9.79 2.91c.75-2.48 1.71-4.9 2.55-7.35l1.3-3.67 1.64-3.52-9.32-4.18-1.76 3.85-1.42 4c-.9 2.64-1.94 5.27-2.75 7.97zm-5 29.75l10.2.5a71.57 71.57 0 0 1 .57-7.75l1.15-7.68-10-1.86-1.26 8.36a81.78 81.78 0 0 0-.58 8.44zm86.51-113.2l2.68 9.85a48.82 48.82 0 0 1 7.43-1.64l3.74-.68c1.24-.22 2.51-.19 3.77-.29l-.81-10.18c-1.42.12-2.86.1-4.27.34l-4.21.75a57.31 57.31 0 0 0-8.25 1.86zm-27.84 12.23l5.4 8.67c2.14-1.44 4.49-2.49 6.72-3.77 1.14-.59 2.24-1.27 3.41-1.8l3.54-1.47-4-9.4-3.93 1.64c-1.29.58-2.5 1.32-3.76 2-2.36 1.38-4.95 2.57-7.3 4.14zm-23.4 19.09l7.38 7.07 5.54-5.45c1.89-1.77 4-3.3 5.95-5l-6.34-8c-2.16 1.82-4.44 3.5-6.49 5.44z"/>
  </g>
<circle cx="542.45" cy="110.3" r="19.07" fill="#daa900" id="Icon_Dot" data-name="Icon Dot"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for all three browsers. Thank you!